# Postfix label text with colon

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I use ASP.NET MVC 3. For my forms, I align the label's text to the right. Also, there is a colon between the label and the input field.

```
Firstname: [          ]
     Last: [          ]
```

**Can I automatically insert this colon using CSS or some C# code in MVC 3?**

The best thing I came up with so far is to use the `[Display(Name="Firstname:")]` attribute, but this has the side effect of also including this colon in validation messages:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Firstname:")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} character long.", MinimumLength = 1)]
public string Firstname { get; set; }
```

The other alternative was to use the `LabelFor()` method overload, but this forces me to specify the label text twice (once in the Model and once in cshtml file):

```
<div>
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Firstname, "Firstname:")</div>
    <div class="editor-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Firstname)</div>
</div>
```

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Through CSS, you can add the colon via the `after` pseudo class. You can find more information about this pseudo class [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html).

```
.editor-label > label:after {
    content: ": "
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fJQDZ/**

Please note that the `after` pseudo class is not available in IE7.

Comment: Thanks, but is also possible to check if the content length is greater than zero?

Comment: It is not possible to do that using CSS alone. You could use javascript to add a class to an element if the length is greater than zero. And then target those elements using the same CSS in this answer; e.g. `.editor-label > .has-content:after { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to avoid using pseudo-elements, an alternative is to keep `[Display(Name = "Firstname")]` and use the `@Html.DisplayNameFor()` helper with a colon after.

```
<div><!--                                          **colon below**  ⬇   -->
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.FirstName):</div>
    <div class="editor-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Firstname)</div>
</div>
```