# Easy way to overload Html.LabelFor to add a 'suffix'?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to add an extension to html.labelfor, so that I could use something like:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Description, ":")
```

Which would add the semicolon as a suffix in the rendered HTML:

> Description:

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could do this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description,
               string.Format("{0}:", Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Description)))
```

`DisplayNameFor` gives you just the display name for the property without the label markup, so you can use this as part of the `labelText` parameter in `LabelFor` and format it as you please. This way you still get the benefit of dynamically generated label text.

Easily wrapped up in its own helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelWithColonFor<TModel, TValue>(
              this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
              Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    return helper.LabelFor(expression, string.Format("{0}:",
                                              helper.DisplayNameFor(expression)));
}
```

Then:

```
@Html.LabelWithColonFor(m => m.Description)
```

Comment: I got a html-formatted MvcHtmlString as input to the labelText parameter of helper.LabelFor when calling just helper.DisplayNameFor(exptression).  
That causes the output to display special chars such as "ø" as "&oslash;" in the label text.  The simplest solution I found was to decode the encoded html again using HttpUtility.HtmlDecode, like this:  


`return helper.LabelFor(expression, string.Format("{0}:", System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(helper.DisplayNameFor(expression).ToString())));`  
  
I welcome any simpler solutions.

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a duplicate question and answer.

[Postfix label text with colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360840/postfix-label-text-with-colon)

It's nice because the colon is really a design element and not part of the viewModel's displayname attribute. Which is nice because the colon will show up in any validation message that uses the diaplayname attribute

And the css is super easy.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 4.6+ you can make use of [interpolated strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160):

```
<label>@($"{Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Description)}:")</label>
```

Or if you prefer the verbose version

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description, $"{Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Description)}:")
```

Comment: Your "verbose" option is functionally different - `LabelFor` associates the label with the ID of the field, which allows the user to select the field by clicking the label.