# ASP.MVC concatenation in Html.LabelFor helper or model Display Name annotation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, razor-declarative-helpers

In my view i use the Html helper:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.name)
```

The model contains the annotation for getting display name from resources

```
[Display(Name = "name", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Models.ModelName))]
```

My resources provide translations without ":". If I put ":" after Html.LabelFor helper it won't be placed in label tag, but out of it:

```
<label for="name">Name</label>:
```

Is there any way to concatenate a postfix to the Html.LabelFor helper or the Display Name annotation?

Yes I know I can solve this problem by not using labelFor helper at all or concatenating ":" with jQuery, but I'm trying to find an elegant solution.

Comment: is there by any chance a 'Value' attribute?

Comment: Do you mean Value in resource files?

Comment: Like this( although this was for a dropdown list):   *@ Html.DropDownList("CompanyID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @ class = "form-control", @Value = ViewBag.ChosenJB})*

Comment: (without spaces between at symbol and value

Comment: I tried @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, htmlAttributes: new { @Value = ":"}) - but with no result.

Comment: I would do it with CSS.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360840/postfix-label-text-with-colon

Comment: Fran - virtually the same solution has just been posted by Artm but thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use css to add the : if you give your labels a class name:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, { @class = 'postfix'} )
```

CSS:

```
label.postfix:after
{
     content: ":";
}
```

Or you can create an extension helper and call it as

```
@Html.LabelForPostfix(model => model.name)
```

Comment: CSS :after solution seems to be the most elegant combined with the less work effort. Thank you.